# How to keep audio silence with ffmpeg command

Tags: command-line, audio, ffmpeg

I have compressed audio file with silence, we want to keep silence to another format, but ffmpeg command either partially or fully removed the silence part. I tried to use bellow command on ffmpeg prompt:

1. `ffmpeg -c:a libopus -i inputFile.voicemedia -acodec pcm_s16le -ar 8000 outputFile.wav`
2. `ffmpeg -i inputFile.voicemedia -acodec pcm_s16le -ar 8000outputFile.wav`
3. `ffmpeg -i inputFile.voicemedia outputFile.wav`
4. `ffmpeg -i inputFile.voicemedia -acodec pcm_s16le -ac 1 -ar 8000  outputFile.wav`

but not working, please help me have any idea or solution..

thank you

Comment: The extension `.voicemedia` is non-standard. What is the format of the file? Try: `ffmpeg -f ogg -i inputFile.voicemedia -acodec pcm_s16le -ar 8000 outputFile.wav`. Or rename input the file to `inputFile.opus`.

Comment: Actually we download voice from twilio site and store it with .voicemedia extension then converted it to .wav format with silence but not get yet success.
ffmpeg -f ogg -i inputFile.voicemedia -acodec pcm_s16le -ar 8000 outputFile.wav
not working .. shows error
[ogg @ 000001a4aebe2880] cannot find sync word
20220512T102601956!99991592!159!Video.voicemedia: Invalid data found when processing input

extension .voicemedia file playing on window media player with silence but after conversion silence become loss.

Comment: After rename .opus, it keep silence but when converting to .wav again remove silence partially. 1:30 min silence become 24 sec only.

Comment: I don't know what is the format of `inputFile.voicemedia`... You may create silence audio file using FFmpeg: `ffmpeg -f lavfi -i anullsrc=channel_layout=mono:sample_rate=8000 -acodec pcm_s16le -ac 1 -t 90 outputFile.wav`

Answer (score 0):

For files with audio gaps represented by skips in timestamps (as Twilio does), you can use the ffmpeg aresample filter:

```
ffmpeg -i input.opus -af aresample=async=1 output.opus
```

From the ffmpeg documentation:

> This filter is also able to stretch/squeeze the audio data to make it
> match the timestamps or to inject silence / cut out audio to make it
> match the timestamps, do a combination of both or do neither.

See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52845150/use-ffmpeg-to-export-audios-with-gaps-filled